# Adding JDK to netbeans 8.1

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, java-8

I have netbeans set up in a C++ environment. I want to be able to write some java applications. How do I add the java programming environment to netbeans? It asks to run a command line that I know nothing about.

[image]

Comment: You need to download a JDK (not a JRE) first: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html

Comment: Did you download a Netbeans version with all Java modules included? After that follow JDK registration answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the JDK first before installing the plugin for Java/JRE.

You need to manually install the JDK from the Oracle's Official [Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Then, you need to [enable JDK 8 Support in NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk8.html#platform) using the linked tutorial.

Finally, you can proceed with the installation of the desired plugins.

> It asks to run a command line that I know nothing about.

After performing the said steps, you won't need to worry about that. It'd be automatically configured with the listed steps.

Answer (score 0):

Or you install a bundle of JDK+NetBeans from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html and then you can upgrade the installation with C++-Plugins at Tools|Plugins within NB itself.